# Import Eclipse Project To Android Studio error There are unrecoverable errors which must be corrected first

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to android and I have a project made in eclipse and i want to shift it to android studio but when i tried to import that project into Android Studio it gives me the error. I have attached the Image please help me out. i am in a big trouble.[image]

Comment: Where is error report ?

Comment: In Eclipse do a clean + rebuild and then try again. If problem still persists open your XML file and see what is happening in there. Btw there are several questions like yours here on SO. You might want to check them out.